# How to respond to Merci, in a certain situation

Tags: usage

I wrote a prayer for someone who passed-away to someone in Greece who speaks French. They answered back Merci Robert. So how do I respond since there are so many ways to respond, what is the correct way to say your welcome in that instance? They seem to use a very informal dialect. Would de rien be correct? I do not know this person, by the way.

Answer (score 5):

"De rien" might seem a bit flippant for this kind of occasion.

You could use "Il n'y a pas de quoi," "Il n'y a pas de quoi me remercier," or come up with something less formulaic that expresses your actual thoughts on the matter. For example, you could say "C'était normal que je le fasse," "J'étais content de pouvoir le faire," or something similar.

Comment: I believe that 'J'étais content de pouvoir le faire', feels right for this occasion... Merci beaucoup pour votre contribution...

Answer (score 2):

I think the best answer should be : "Je t'en prie" or "Je vous en prie".
This is polite and can be used on formal and informal context.

Comment: " Ce fut un plaisir " work in this case too. This is my favorite, very polite it works in every situations

Comment: Well, I like this, but it's a prayer for someone who died... so, not sure how pleasurable it should be... I believe "J'étais content de pouvoir le faire". felt, like the best fit, for the occasion! ..........Merci beaucoup...